# navigation bar shifted while coming back from movie player of iphone app

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uiinterfaceorientation

[image: iPad Example]

I am showing the mp4 video in iphone app using following code:

```
enter code here
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-mp4\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

It works great. it also opens movieplayer for iphone app on clicking.
But when I return from the movieplayer, it shows a white space over the navigation bar, shifting the navigation bar downwards.

I have tried it on simulator and iphone device both.

The navigation bar looks like this:
[image: iPad example]

Comment: are you doing something to your navBar before? like customizing it?

Comment: Yes i am just setting a tint color of the navigation bar......

Comment: I think its not the navbar that is wrong but the view that uses the navbar. I recommend checking out the frame of the view and make sure it covers all of the device's window (320x468).

Comment: @totumus i tried with the view thing.... i have added image showing a problem root... the space that appears above the movieplayer....... kindly help... it is eating out my brain and time.......

Comment: Could you add your code of how you load your views viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear/etc on both the movieplayerview and the view that you are returning to. Apart from that add also the code which makes you navigate to both views. The problem has to be somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced something that sounds similar, this is my advice :

Have a look at the xib for the view in Xcode, and look for the page properties. Check that the height is 480, not 460.

Comment: How about 
    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]; ?